# Bramus Router issue in mvc

Tags: php, model-view-controller

[Bramus/Router](https://github.com/bramus/router)

i'm trying the demo in the public folder and it is not working. --> 404 error

in the root folder, without the rewriting it's working.

the problem is the value of $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"].  It is /index.php in the root and /public/index.php after rewrite to the public folder.

any suggestions?

folder structure is typical MVC structure with app and public folder

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L]
```

file structure

```
Root
--app
--public
----index.php
--vendor
--.htaccess
```

Comment: Can you show how your files are organized and which folder is the document root? Usually you have htaccess in the public folder (which usually is the web servers document root), which means you you should only have `^(.*)$ index.php`, not `^(.*)$ public/index.php`.

Comment: By adding the RewriteBase directive and setting it to /public/, you explicitly instruct the server to consider the public folder as the base directory for rewriting.

``# Rewrite base to the public folder
RewriteBase /public/``

Comment: this RewriteBase directive in the root folder? Because that is not working

Comment: Why are you not just setting "document root" to be the `/public` folder? Also, use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.